# Zend Framework error when uploaded on sub domain

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I had uploaded my project on `zend.domain.com` after creating sub-domain in `domain.com`. So originally my code is at `domain.com/zend`.
When I try to run the project it is giving me these errors:

> Warning: include_once(Zend/View.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/domain/public_html/zend/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend/View.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/domain/public_html/zend/application/../library:/home/domain/public_html/zend/library:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/brainbud/public_html/zend/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_View' not found in /home/brainbud/public_html/zend/library/Zend/Application/Resource/View.php on line 69

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteRule ^(blog|forum)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your .htaccess file. You either missed some library parts while uploading them or library/Zend is not  correct in your include path.

- Re-Upload Zend
- Check index.php for the correct path. (What does `ls /home/domain/public_html/zend/library` tell you?)

Usually:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```